# BSTR and Strings

Tags: string, visual-c++, com, bstr

```
BSTR DoSOmething()
{
   return L"";
}
```

OR is it okay to pass TCHAR * to API taking BSTR as input parameter.

Is it okay to convert wchar_t string into BSTR via a return statement.Will it cause some memory corruption?

Comment: Have a look at the Guide to BSTR and C String Conversions http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4829/Guide-to-BSTR-and-C-String-Conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not OK because some APIs expect not just a `WCHAR*` pointer, which `BSTR` also is, but a real `BSTR` pointer with length information attached. Still casting this way might often work out well, and this might be misleading.

Everything about BSTRs: [Eric's Complete Guide To BSTR Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx).

A related quote from there:

> 2) A BSTR must be allocated and freed with the SysAlloc* family of
>   functions.  A PWSZ can be an automatic-storage buffer from the stack
>   or allocated with malloc, new, LocalAlloc or any other memory
>   allocator.
>
> 3) A BSTR is of fixed length.  A PWSZ may be of any length, limited
>   only by the amount of valid memory in its buffer.
>
> 4) A BSTR always points to the first valid character in the buffer.  A
>   PWSZ may be a pointer to the middle or end of a string buffer.